# What do the parameters in Hangfire's BackgroundJobServerOptions mean, such as ShutdownTimeout, StopTimeout and ServerTimeout

Tags: hangfire

I found the constructor of `BackgroundJobServerOptions` in the official git code base. But there is no comment explaining their respective functions, nor is it stated in the official documentation. Can someone explain?
Thanks!

```cs
public BackgroundJobServerOptions()
{
    WorkerCount = Math.Min(Environment.ProcessorCount * 5, MaxDefaultWorkerCount);
    Queues = new[] { EnqueuedState.DefaultQueue };
    StopTimeout = BackgroundProcessingServerOptions.DefaultStopTimeout;
    ShutdownTimeout = BackgroundProcessingServer.DefaultShutdownTimeout;
    SchedulePollingInterval = DelayedJobScheduler.DefaultPollingDelay;
    HeartbeatInterval = BackgroundProcessingServerOptions.DefaultHeartbeatInterval;
    ServerTimeout = ServerWatchdog.DefaultServerTimeout;
    ServerCheckInterval = ServerWatchdog.DefaultCheckInterval;
    CancellationCheckInterval = ServerJobCancellationWatcher.DefaultCheckInterval;
            
    FilterProvider = null;
    Activator = null;
    TimeZoneResolver = null;
    TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.Default;
}
```

Comment: Please add the github link of the code too.

Comment: FYI  https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/BackgroundJobServerOptions.cs